# Combination sum with Python dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, combinatorics

I have a dict of fantasy football (soccer) data, where the first value in the tuple is a price and the second is an expected points for the season. A segment of it can be seen below:

```
 'Romeu': [4.5, 57.0],
 'Neves': [5.5, 96.0],
 'Townsend': [6.0, 141.0],
 'Lucas Moura': [7.5, 105.0],
 'Martial': [7.5, 114.0],
 'David Silva': [7.5, 177.0],
 'Fraser': [7.5, 180.0],
 'Richarlison': [8.0, 138.0],
 'Bernardo Silva': [8.0, 174.0],
 'Sigurdsson': [8.0, 187.0],
```

What I would like to do is write a program that allows me to set a price limit and return the combination of a fixed length e.g. n=5 which has the maximum score.

So if I set the price limit to 32 and I want 5 players, it returns Romeu, Neves, Townsend, Sigurdsson, Fraser.

Can someone please give me a hint in the right direction? I have no idea how to get started with this.

Comment: AFAIK this is very much a non-trivial problem. It sounds exactly like the famous [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). As it is so widespread there are lots of approaches.

Comment: This problem probably does not have a simple solution. This sounds like "The knapsack (or rucksack) problem" to me. Google that for plenty of reading to do, and a few sample implementations! https://xkcd.com/287/

Comment: Sounds like a [constraint problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem). [PuLP](https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/) might be a good package to look into.

Comment: Got it! This looks like it'll do the job for me with some tweaks. Any reason why I shouldn't use a brute force approach?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EdLw7hjAyNU

Comment: Brute force will take n! steps for a team of size n.  Just for players on the field that is over 360 thousand combinations to check.  For a full roster it is 1.551121 * 10^25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a brute force approach that I've tried with a selection of 5 players out of 115 (1 minute, 42 seconds on my laptop). Increasing the selection to 20 players out of only 100 will take over 100,000 years to execute. Even 20 of 50 will take 4 days.

```
from itertools import combinations

# Set the following parameters as desired
nplayers = 5
price = 32

players = {
    'Romeu': [4.5, 57.0],
    'Neves': [5.5, 96.0],
    'Townsend': [6.0, 141.0],
    'Lucas Moura': [7.5, 105.0],
    'Martial': [7.5, 114.0],
    'David Silva': [7.5, 177.0],
    'Fraser': [7.5, 180.0],
    'Richarlison': [8.0, 138.0],
    'Bernardo Silva': [8.0, 174.0],
    'Sigurdsson': [8.0, 187.0],
}

if len(players) < nplayers:
    raise IndexError("You selected {nplayers} players but there are only {len(players)} to choose from")

# Create a list of all combinations of players, store as triples (name, cost, score)
combos = combinations(((h, *t) for h, t in players.items()), nplayers)

top_score = 0

for c in combos:
    if sum(p[1] for p in c) <= price:
        score = sum(p[2] for p in c)
        if score > top_score:
            top_teams = [c]
            continue
        elif score == top_score:
            top_teams.append(c)

if top_score:
    print(top_teams)
else:
    print(f"You can't afford a team for only {price}")
```

Output

```
[(('Romeu', 4.5, 57.0), ('Neves', 5.5, 96.0), ('Townsend', 6.0, 141.0), ('Fraser', 7.5, 180.0), ('Sigurdsson', 8.0, 187.0))]
```

Comment: Wow great stuff! It works a treat in selecting 3 players from 20 when position is limited to forward. For midfielders it's 5 from 115 so a different task altogether...Where do you suggest I get looking?

You've not misinterpreted my objective. Careless mistake on my part

Comment: 5 of 115 has 153,476,148 combinations. I was looking at this https://developers.google.com/optimization/bin/knapsack but it doesn't let you to select the number of players, it will just find a bunch for the price that will have the highest score. I found this in SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45977151/knapsack-with-limit-on-total-items-used that discusses approaches to this kind of problem but no suitable libraries were mentioned, just research papers.

Comment: You still might get away with brute force. I've changed the answer to a simpler approach that just does a linear search. Since it only has to process each combination once it won't take forever even for 153M items. The combinations will also be generated on the fly so it doesn't all have to be in memory at once. I tested it with 5/115 and it completed in 1 minute 52 seconds in only 5MB of memory. I've removed some of the fancy stuff with picking the lowest cost maximum score team as it is easy enough to replicate or eyeball from the result.

Comment: Added a `continue` statement reduced the run time to 1:43. The CPU on my laptop is 6 cores with 12 logical processors so it might be possible to use multiple threads to speed it up some more. I was also thinking that the brute force approach has a potential advantage in ease of adding new factors or constraints.